# Specifying the answer you are looking for

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

#### Problem

When asking a question, I sometimes find that I do not receive an answer to the extent I was looking for.

For example: I ask for an explanation of the difference between a pen and pencil. In the back of my mind I want to know the exact performance differences, pros and cons, etc. between the two writing utensils. Instead I receive answers only going over the fact that one uses lead and the other uses ink (no further information). I have this problem even when I clearly express my question at times.

#### Question

Is it wrong to specify the type of answer you are expecting to receive (for clarification)? Or better yet, is it even worth it?

#### Specification (*implementing my example*)

In this case I am looking for a yes/no answer with a further explanation over this process' implications/benefits.

I am hoping that in this way I can tailor my answers at all times to have all of the information I am looking for.

Comment: The more specific you are, the more specific answerers *can* be, but that doesn't mean you're guaranteed the kinda answer you're looking for. SE tends to reward TFGITW, and so many people play that game to the exclusion of others.

Comment: @DanBron Do you mean TGFITW i.e. The Greatest Fans In The World?  In any event, those who take the time to really learn how to use the site, do seem to benefit from it the most.  Getting clear answers to any questions they ask is one of the most obvious benefits.

Comment: Sounds like the question you're asking is Too Broad.  Most "What's the difference between A and B?" questions are.  For them to not be you generally need to specify a very specific trait that you're trying to compare the two things against, rather than asking for literally all of the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes/No seems like an unwise dichotomy to insist should start an answer to a question like this because the first word that comes to my mind is Unwise.

When writing any question I think the thing to focus on is asking clearly.

On the Meta of my main site of [GIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com) I have offered some [advice for framing a good question](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3353/115) and I think quite a bit of it will hold up on most sites.

Personally, I find questions that are prescriptive about the type of answers they want can come across as demanding, and as a result, even if I had something that may have helped the asker, but seemed not to strictly fit, then I would move on.  That saves my time and the asker will not know whether they missed something useful.

Comment: I had not thought of it that way. I can see how it would come across as a little demanding. Thanks!